# How do fighter jets measure how high they are?

Tags: flight-instruments, aerospace-materials

1. I know most of the commercial planes use altimeter to find how high they are. I was just curious in finding out what fighter jets use to to find their height and what are the other technologies that could be used other than pitot tubes to find speed of an aircraft or fighter jet.

<strike>2. What material are used to make pitot tubes in aeroplane?</strike>

Comment: Why do you think military aircraft are significantly different in this regard to commercial planes?

Comment: Also, please ask only one question in each question post. The expertise needed to answer your two sub-questions is not the same, and they touch on very different subject areas, so it's best to ask them as two separate questions. (The fact that you felt the need to separate them is a hint that they are too different to fit within a single question.) Questions that ask multiple separate questions at once are liable to being closed as "too broad". You can avoid that by making sure to only ask a single question per question post.

Answer (score 1):

Fighter jets have the same system as commercial aircraft: An altimeter based upon external air pressure. this measures their altitude relative to pre-defined atmospheric conditions. Many will also include a secondary system that relies on GPS (or local equivalent) signals to produce a height above the reference geoid rather than an atmospheric datum.

Regarding your second question - you should only post one question per topic. An answer is difficult as the construction varies significantly between manufacturers. Many pitots are made of steel variants, however.